# Power keeps knocking on one side of the breaker

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Power keeps knocking on one side of the breaker- the left side to be exact. I noticed about 4 months ago when the ac would turn on power in the kitchen, it would flicker. I honestly thought nothing of it but it got so much worse. The power would flicker 3 or 4 times and scare me half to death.

Well, about 2 weeks ago it went haywire. It knocked the power on the left side of the breaker box but didn't knock the main breaker it was fluctuating like dimming and flashing. I did knock the main breaker cause I was terrified. Anyway since that, I did turn it back on and all seemed fine again but still flickering when ac came on, then noticed it happened again when the fridge did and all of those are on the left side of the breaker box.

My power company has been utterly useless they have came out 3 times but only checking when it's working the voltage from pole to house. So I have a tester and when the power went crazy and knocked the left side, I checked and the left side showed 60 or nothing and the right 125, which it should be getting 125 on both. I just don't know what could be the cause. While typing this it started to rain and the power only on the left side of the breaker went crazy again. I'm just at a loss can anyone help me any suggestions any help or advice is greatly appreciated thank you all.

Comment: Where on the planet are you, please? Your location may result in different required answers.

Comment: The power company will normally only check the voltage and connections up to and including the load side of the meter. After that, it's a customer problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "knocked" or "knocking" here? That's not a description I've heard in relation to electrical power.

Answer (score 3):

The following is under the assumption you are in North America and have split-phase power:

If you confirmed this:

> It knocked the power on the left side of the breaker box

as meaning every other breaker on the whole house was losing power, then this could be either a bad power leg outside, through the meter box and into the main panel somewhere, or it could be a bad connection in the panel itself, either a bad main breaker or a broken bus bar.

If it's only the breaker that powers the AC, then that breaker or the wire being fed by the breaker is broken.

Note that this:

> all of those are on the left side of the breaker box.

is not really consistent with many electrical panels. Most panels swap the main feed going down each row of side-by-side breakers: First row gets fed by leg A, second row by leg B, third row by leg A again, fourth by leg B, etc down the panel. It would take a great deal of simultaneous failures to get the full one side of the panel to stop working. You may need to doublecheck the results of your testing.

Since the power company confirmed their wires to the house, you'll probably need an electrician to look at the main wires after the power company's.

Don't put it off. Any of these problems could be a fire hazard.